# buttonClicked() method for button on QMessageBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I want to call "removeDuplicate" method when 'Ok' button on QMessageBox is clicked. But when I click the button the method doesn't execute. What should I do?
Here is my code snippet :

```
def removeDuplicate(self):
        curItem = self.listWidget_2.currentItem()
        self.listWidget_2.takeItem(curItem)

def error_popup(self):
        msg=QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setText("You can't select more than one wicket-keeper.")
        msg.setWindowTitle(" ")
        msg.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Critical)
        x = msg.exec_()
        msg.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
        msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.removeDuplicate)
```

Comment: See [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/116138/buttonclicked-for-button-on-qmessagebox/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.error_popup()

    def removeDuplicate(self):
        print('def removeDuplicate(self): ...')
#        curItem = self.listWidget_2.currentItem()
#        self.listWidget_2.takeItem(curItem)

    def error_popup(self):
        msg = QMessageBox.critical(
            self, 
            'Title', 
            "You can't select more than one wicket-keeper", 
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel
        )
        if msg == QMessageBox.Yes:
#            msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.removeDuplicate)
            print('Ok')
            self.removeDuplicate()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```